# Azure Multi tenant application not visible to certain tenants

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

We have a multi tenant azure ad application that is not visible in certain other tenants. Is there a tenant level setting to allow third party applications?

We run the following command from the azure cli to see if hte application is visible

`az ad app show --id appID`

We get the following error:

(I have xxx out the application id)

> Resource 'xxxxx' does not exist or one of its queried
>   reference-property objects are not present. Traceback (most recent
>   call last):   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   SDKs\Azure\CLI2\lib\site-packages\azure\cli\main.py", line 36, in main
>       cmd_result = APPLICATION.execute(args)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   SDKs\Azure\CLI2\lib\site-packages\azure\cli\core\application.py", line
>   216, in execute
>       result = expanded_arg.func(params)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   SDKs\Azure\CLI2\lib\site-packages\azure\cli\core\commands__init__.py",
>   line 381, in **call**
>       return self.handler(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   SDKs\Azure\CLI2\lib\site-packages\azure\cli\core\commands__init__.py",
>   line 640, in _execute_command
>       raise client_exception   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\lib\site-packages\azure\cli\core\commands__init__.py",
>   line 628, in _execute_command
>       exception_handler(ex)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\lib\site-packages\azure\cli\core\util.py", line 49, in
>   empty_on_404
>       raise ex   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\lib\site-packages\azure\cli\core\commands__init__.py",
>   line 612, in _execute_command
>       result = op(client, **kwargs) if client else op(**kwargs)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   SDKs\Azure\CLI2\lib\site-packages\azure\cli\command_modules\role\custom.py",
>   line 455, in show_application
>       return client.get(object_id)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   SDKs\Azure\CLI2\lib\site-packages\azure\graphrbac\operations\applications_operations.py",
>   line 272, in get
>       raise models.GraphErrorException(self._deserialize, response) azure.graphrbac.models.graph_error.GraphErrorException: Resource
>   'xxxx' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects
>   are not present.

Answer (score 0):

Users in other tenant needs to consent the permissions to the multi-tenant App. Then the Applicaition will occurs in that tenant as a sp. So you may forget to do this step:

> When a user from a different tenant signs in to the application for
>   the first time, Azure AD asks them to consent to the permissions
>   requested by the application. If they consent, then a representation
>   of the application called a service principal is created in the user’s
>   tenant, and sign-in can continue.

After finishing this, you can use `az ad sp list` to check if the sp is in that tenant.

Also, you need to ensure your multi-tenant app is configured well before you starting to login it. For more details about How to sign in any AAD user using the multi-tenant app, please refer to [**this document**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devhowto-multi-tenant-overview).

Comment: The application is up and configured. Our users don't interact through the UI but interact directly with the command line "az ad sp create --applicationId appId". This used to work fine before but doesn't seem to work now.